# How to decode in C a stream from this noname almost-UVC grayscale camera

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, mjpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

**Edit:** I found the cause. The stream always begins with something which is not a JPEG. Only after it there is a normal MJPEG stream. Interestingly, not all of the small examples of using V4L2/MJPEG decoders can divide what the camera produces properly into frames. Something called `capturev4l2.c` is a rare example of doing it properly. Possibly there is some detail, which decides if the camera's bugginess is worked around or not.

I have a noname almost-UVC-compliant camera (it fails several compatibility tests). This is a relatively cheap global shutter camera, and thus I would like to use it instead of something properly documented. It outputs what is reported (and properly played) by `mplayer` as

```
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffmjpeg] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MJPEG)
```

`ffprobe` shows the following:

```
[mjpeg @ 0x55c086dcc080] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from '/home/sc/Desktop/a.raw':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
```

But as opposed to `mplayer`, it is unable to play it.

I tried `decode_jpeg_raw` from `mjpegtools`, it complains about the header, which seems to change with each captured stream. So does not look like an unwrapped stream of JPEG images.

I thus tried `0_hello_world.c` from libavcodec/libavformat, but its stops at `avformat_open_input()` with an error `Invalid data found when processing input`. A 100-frame sample file is sitting here [a.raw](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=54610387792933721293&t=5461038779293372129323472). Do you have any idea how to determine a method of decoding it in C into anything plain bitmap?

The file is grayscale, does not begin with a constant value, `guvcview` and `mplayer` are the only players I know, which can decode it without artifacts...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have raw stream, I think what you need is a decoder with parser.
Check this `decode_video.c` example on ffmpeg:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c

Change necessary parts accordingly, like `avcodec_find_decoder(...)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It shows "codec not found". Another program which does not work with the camera. Like the device were faulty or whatever. Still, `mplayer` works somehow with it.

Comment: DId you try `avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG)` ?

Comment: Yes, did not work. But I found the cause, see the edit.